# F sharp adding lists

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-data, fsharp.data.sqlclient

how do you convert an obj list to int type. I am trying to add two lists using a map function below but it doesn't work on obj lists.

```
let query f= 
 seq{
let cmd = new OleDbCommand( "SELECT *  FROM F" );
let conn = new OleDbConnection( @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
Data Source=D:\Users\df\Documents\Vfolio.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;" )

conn.Open()
let DAdapt = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM F",conn)
let DTab = new DataSet()
let i= DAdapt.Fill(DTab)
let rowCol = DTab.Tables.[0].Rows
let rowCount = rowCol.Count
 for i in 0 .. (rowCount - 1) do
           yield f (rowCol.[i])
   }
 let u= query(fun row -> row.[0])
 let a= List.ofSeq u
 let v=query(fun row -> row.[1])
 let b= List.ofSeq v
 let c = List.map2 (fun x y-> x + y) a b
```

error msg: The type 'obj' does not support the operator '+'

Comment: You could try to use `Seq.cast` in `let a= List.ofSeq (Seq.cast<int> u)` and in `let b = `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `row.[i]` returns type `obj`, your `u` and `v` become `seq<obj>`, and thus your `a` and `b` become type `List<obj>`, and therefore `x` and `y` are inferred to have type `obj`, and of course, you can't add two `obj`s, which is exactly what the compiler tells you.

If you are sure that `row.[0]` and `row.[1]` are numbers of some kind, you should apply the appropriate cast, for example:

```
let u= query(fun row -> row.[0] :?> int)
let a= List.ofSeq u
let v=query(fun row -> row.[1] :?> int)
let b= List.ofSeq v
let c = List.map2 (fun x y-> x + y) a b
```

You can apply this cast in other places, too, depending on your taste and requirements, for example:

```
let c = List.map2 (fun x y-> (x :?> int) + (y :?> int)) a b
```

Or:

```
let a= u |> Seq.cast<int> |> List.ofSeq
let b= v |> Seq.cast<int> |> List.ofSeq
```

But I like the first example best, because it applies the cast at the earliest known point and results in the least amount of extra code.

But beware: if `row.[0]` turns out to be not an `int` at runtime, you will get an `InvalidCastException`.

**P.S.** In your `List.map2` call, you could specify `(+)` directly instead of wrapping it in an extra lambda:

```
List.map2 (+) a b
```

**P.P.S** Also, it seems that your `List.ofSeq` calls are wasteful, for `Seq` also has a `map2`:

```
let u = query(fun row -> row.[0] :?> int)
let v = query(fun row -> row.[1] :?> int)
let c = Seq.map2 (+) u v |> List.ofSeq
```

**P.P.P.S** Also, have you noticed that each of the two calls to `query` generates its own DB connection, command, adapter, and dataset? Did you intend this or did you mean to only have one connection and then fetch different columns from the result? If so, you should only call `query` once:

```
let c = query( fun row -> (row.[0] :?> int) + (row.[1] :?> int) ) |> List.ofSeq
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation,I just realized that some of the values in the query are null.